# Dígito verificador de RUT con vectores

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que retorne el dígito verificador del RUT en Uruguay.

Muestro a continuación, pero el programa se tranca. Además debería agregar el dígito al final del vector.

El dígito se construye así:

1. Se toma el número de RUT hasta la penúltima posición, o sea, los 11 primeros dígitos.
2. Se multiplica cada dígito por los siguientes factores: 4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2.
3. Se suman los productos obtenidos.
4. El probable dígito verificador es lo que falta para llegar a la suma obtenida. Para eso, se divide el resultado de la suma entre 11. Le resto 11 menos el resto obtenido.
5. Si el dígito es menor que 10, es el verdadero dígito verificador. Si es 11, el dígito es 0. Si es 10, el número se desecha.
6. Debe controlarse que las dos primeras posiciones estén en el rango 01 a 21. De la 3a a 8a posición debe ser distinto de 0. Las posiciones 9 y 10 deben ser 0.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){


int resultado=0;
int digito=0;
int suma=0;
int factor []={4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
int rut [11], rut1 [11];

//pide y lee rut
printf ("Digita el RUT sin dígito verificador.\n");
for (int i=0; i<11;i++){
  scanf ("%d",&rut[i]);
}

//Verifica que las dos primeras posiciones estén entre 1 y 21,
//de la 3a a la 8a posición debe ser distinto de 0,
//y las posiciones 9 y 10 deben ser 0.
if (rut[0] && rut[1] >1 && rut[0] && rut[1] < 22 &&
    rut[3] != 0 && rut[4] != 0 && rut[5] != 0 && rut[6] != 0 && rut[7] != 0 && rut[8] != 0 &&
    rut [9]&& rut[10] == 0){

  //multiplico dígitos por factor
  for (int j=0;j<11;j++){
      rut1[j]= rut[j]*factor[j];
  }

  //sumo los elementos
  for (int m=0;m<11;m++)
      suma+=rut1[m];

  //divido resultado entre 11. El dígito es 11 - resto

  resultado= 11 - (suma%11);

  //si resultado es menor que 10, ese el el dígito verificador.
  if (resultado<10)
      resultado=digito;
  //si resultado es 11, el dígito verificador es 0.
      else if (resultado==11)
          digito=0;
  //si resultado es 10, el número se desecha.
      else if (digito==10)
          digito=0;

      for (int n=0; n<11;n++)
        printf ("Rut inicial: %d\n", rut[n]);
      for (int r=0; r<11;r++)
        printf ("Rut multiplicado por factor: %d\n", rut1[r]);
      printf ("Suma dígitos: %d\n", suma);
      printf ("El dígito es: %d", digito);
  }

else

printf ("Número de RUT no corresponde.\n");
}
```

Comment: en tu pregunta deberias explicar la estructura o reglas que cumple el RUT para que los usuarios de otros paises te ayuden :)

Comment: Eso lo hice de forma comentada en el código, paso a paso. Igual lo aclaro.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacerlo en la parte superior de forma detallada, eso mejoraria mucho su pregunta, ya que el lector podria mostrarte otra forma de implementar el algoritmo sin necesidad de encontrar el error en el tuyo.

Comment: Listo! Ya lo agregué! Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Yendo a tu codigo, tu estas creando un array llamado ruc de 11 elementos, pero veo que en el for que uses para leer los datos tiene 15 iteraciones ¿no crees que es incorrecto?

Comment: `rut[3], rut [4], rut [5], rut [6], rut [7], rut [8] != 0` es lo mismo que `rut[8] != 0`.

Comment: Una desatención mía lo del for, ya lo modifiqué, pero sigue el error. Si pongo rut[8] me contempla de rut[3] a rut[8]? o sea, era esa mi intención.. de la posición 3 a la 8 tiene que ser distinto de 0

Comment: @Adri C *no entiende* lo que quieres hacer, tienes que hacer la comprobacion explicita, es decir uno a uno, es decir `rut[3] != 0 &&  rut[4] != 0 && rut[5] != 0 && rut[6] != 0 && rut[7] != 0 && rut[8] != 0`

Comment: @eyllanesc eso puede ser resumido a `rut[3] && rut[4] && ... && rut[8]` :P

Comment: @NaCl tienes razon, fui muy explicito ;-)

Comment: Y donde se tranca?

Comment: Me pide el RUT y luego se tranca.

Comment: @Adri usa un debugger para ver donde se *tranca*, o usa impresionas para saber hasta donde avanza(es una forma rudimentaria de depurar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Me pide el RUT y luego se tranca

No se *tranca*. Tu pretendes que el programa realice una lectura dígito a dígito, pero eso no se consigue tal y como tu lo estás intentando:

```
for (int i=0; i<11;i++){
  scanf ("%d",&rut[i]);
}
```

Tu le estás diciendo a `scanf` que tiene que leer un entero cada vez... pero es que un entero puede tener varios dígitos... ¿Cómo esperas que el programa *sepa* que tu únicamente quieres leer un dígito cada vez? Desde luego con `"%d"` no puedes.

Prueba a leer caracteres y, seguidamente, conviertes el caracter a dígito numérico:

```
for (int i=0; i<11;i++){
  char c;
  scanf ("%c",&c);
  rut[i] = c - '0';
}
```

Por otro lado, piensa que la entrada en C no se procesa hasta que no se detecta un salto de línea. No esperes que el programa empiece a funcionar hasta que no introduzcas dicho salto de línea.

Answer (score 0):

aquí tienes para poder hacer el código verificador (RUN),espero sea de tu ayuda, la verdad no es tan difícil tienes que investigar como hacer el cifrado cesar y dsp el resto se ahce solo, si quieres progresar te recomiendo que sigas activo a esta web

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
int run=0,i,resto,run_inv,no,n8,n7,n6,n5,n4,n3,n2,n1,suma,digito_verificador;

printf("Por favor ingrese su Run: "); //run de prueba:20277255 este rut debes poner o cualquiera que tenga de codigo verificador  "2"
scanf("%i",&run);

while(run>0) //para calcular el run inverso
{
    resto= run%10;
    run = run/10;
    run_inv= run_inv*10+resto;

}
no=run_inv/10;           /
n8=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;           // todos estos son pa calcular los digitos en unidades y para ordenarlos.
n7=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n6=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n5=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n4=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n3=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n2=run_inv-(no*10);

run_inv=no;
no=run_inv/10;
n1=run_inv-(no*10);

suma= (n1*2)+(n2*3)+(n3*4)+(n4*5)+(n5*6)+(n6*7)+(n7*2)+(n8*3); //la suma y multiplicacion de los "N"

resto= suma%11;

digito_verificador= 11-resto;

if (digito_verificador==2){               //cifrado sas(cesar)
    printf("\nRun valido. Acceso permitido\n");
    if(digito_verificador<10000000);
}
return 0;
```

}